# How to dynamically hide/show a lightning-accordion-section?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How would I create an aura component on an opportunity page layout with 6 accordion sections, one for each opportunity stage, and automatically hides all sections except the one related to the current stage?

For example:

If the opportunity is currently in Stage 3, the accordion menu would display:

```
 > [Stage 1 Header]
 > [Stage 2 Header]
 V [Stage 3 Header]
    ....content....
    ....content....
 > [Stage 4 Header]
 > [Stage 5 Header]
 > [Stage 6 Header]
```

Then, without a page refresh required, when the stage changes to "Stage 4", it would automatically collapse the Stage 3 section, and open the Stage 4 section.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] to show your work or progress so far, and identify a specific problem the community can assist you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code it should work and let me know if it works. When updating the stage, the component will not refresh as i am using Lightning Data Service.

**AccordianList.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionwithoutheader" 
                controller="OpptyCtrl"
                access="global" >
    
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityRecord" type="Opportunity"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="stageNames" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="activeStage" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
    
    <force:recordData aura:id="opportunityRecordCmp"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Id,StageName"
                      targetFields="{!v.opportunityRecord}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}" 
                      mode="VIEW"/>
    
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" activeSectionName="{!v.activeStage}">
            <aura:iteration var="num" items="{!v.stageNames}" indexVar="idx">
                <lightning:accordionSection name="{!num}" label="{!num}"></lightning:accordionSection>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:accordion>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**AccordianController.js**

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.doServerSideCall(component, 'getOppStageNames', 'null').then(
            function(ContactInfo) {
                component.set("v.stageNames", ContactInfo);
                component.set("v.activeStage", component.get("v.opportunityRecord").StageName);
            }
        );
    },
    recordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
        let changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
        
        if (changeType === "ERROR") { /* handle error; do this first! */ }
        else if (changeType === "LOADED") {
            let stageName = component.get("v.opportunityRecord");
            component.set("v.activeStage", stageName.StageName);
        } else if (changeType === "CHANGED" && (('StageName' in event.getParams().changedFields))) {
            component.set("v.activeStage", event.getParams().changedFields.StageName.value);
        }
    }
});
```

**AccordianHelper.js**

```
({
    doServerSideCall : function(component, apexAction, params) {
        let self = this;
        try {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                let action = component.get("c."+apexAction+"");
                if( params != 'null' ) { action.setParams( params ); }
                action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                    let state = response.getState();
                    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                        resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                    }
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(action);
            });
        } catch(exception) { }
    }
})
```

**OpptyCtrl.cls**

```
public class OpptyCtrl {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getOppStageNames() {
        List<String> stageNameMap = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.stagename.getDescribe();    
        List<Schema.picklistEntry> vls = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();    
        for(Schema.picklistEntry v:vls) {
            stageNameMap.add(v.getValue());
        }
        return stageNameMap;
    }
}
```